# Should i put CameraController to getxController?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, clean-architecture

I saw in the getx documents that GetxController is business logic class. When i try to seperate business logic in widget, i have an issue about some controllers such as CameraController, QRViewController,MediaPlayer,... Should i put all things in GetxController or keep this in widget?

**qr_code.dart**

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:clean_architecture_getx/controller/qr_code/qr_code_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';

class QrCodeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const QrCodeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _QrCodeScreenState();
}

class _QrCodeScreenState extends State<QrCodeScreen> {
  final scanQrController = Get.put(ScanQrController());
  QRViewController? qrViewController;
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');

  // In order to get hot reload to work we need to pause the camera if the platform
  // is android, or resume the camera if the platform is iOS.
  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      qrViewController!.pauseCamera();
    }
    qrViewController!.resumeCamera();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 4, child: _buildQrView(context)),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Obx(() {
                    if (scanQrController.result.value.code != null) {
                      return Text(
                          'Barcode Type: ${describeEnum(scanQrController.result
                              .value.format)}   Data: ${scanQrController.result
                              .value.code}');
                    } else {
                      return const Text('Scan a code');
                    }
                  }),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await qrViewController?.toggleFlash();
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                            child: FutureBuilder(
                              future: qrViewController?.getFlashStatus(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                return Text('Flash: ${snapshot.data}');
                              },
                            )),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await qrViewController?.flipCamera();
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                            child: FutureBuilder(
                              future: qrViewController?.getCameraInfo(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.data != null) {
                                  return Text(
                                      'Camera facing ${describeEnum(
                                          snapshot.data!)}');
                                } else {
                                  return const Text('loading');
                                }
                              },
                            )),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await qrViewController?.pauseCamera();
                          },
                          child: const Text('pause',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await qrViewController?.resumeCamera();
                          },
                          child: const Text('resume',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildQrView(BuildContext context) {
    // For this example we check how width or tall the device is and change the scanArea and overlay accordingly.
    var scanArea = (MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .width < 400 ||
        MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height < 400)
        ? 150.0
        : 300.0;
    // To ensure the Scanner view is properly sizes after rotation
    // we need to listen for Flutter SizeChanged notification and update controller
    return QRView(
      key: qrKey,
      onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
      overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
          borderColor: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderLength: 30,
          borderWidth: 10,
          cutOutSize: scanArea),
      onPermissionSet: (ctrl, p) => _onPermissionSet(context, ctrl, p),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.qrViewController = controller;
    });
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      debugPrint('barcode: ${scanData.code}');
      scanQrController.updateBarCode(scanData);
    });
  }

  void _onPermissionSet(BuildContext context, QRViewController ctrl, bool p) {
    log('${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}_onPermissionSet $p');
    if (!p) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('no Permission')),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    qrViewController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**qr_code_controller.dart**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';

class ScanQrController extends GetxController {
  final result = Barcode(null, BarcodeFormat.unknown, null).obs;

  void onQrViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {}

  void updateBarCode(Barcode barcode) {
    result.value = barcode;
  }
}
```

Should i put QRViewController to ScanQrController (GetxController) or keep it in widget?

Answer (score 0):

Put the UI in a view, and put the business logic inside a controller. Have a GetX Controller per feature. It would be more helpful if you could provide an example of your code.

Comment: I edited my question, please help me through this stuff